# Disable -2 Permalink Addition

Tags: permalinks

I am aware that WordPress forbids slugs for pages ending in numerics alone and automatically appends '-2' when they occur. However, other permalink work arounds will not do in my case and I would prefer WordPress simply 'lose' this rule so that numeric slugs will be allowed, and the '-2' will be added only in the case of true file conflicts, i.e. having an image and page both named the same number.

How do you disable WordPress from automatically rejecting numeric slugs except in the case of true conflicts?

**EDIT.** Since it was asked. I have folders of organized events, with the years they occurred.

So my pages will look like Event1/2019/...., but of course when I try to use a page 2019, it wants the '-2' so that the url will instead be Event1/2019-2/.... I would like to eliminate the '-2' of the 2019. There are no images or other files labeled 2019, this is not a file conflict but rather WordPress allowing pure numerics only to appear on post permalinks and not page permalinks.

Comment: Can you provide some additional details? For instance, what's a post title/slug that you are having problems with?

Comment: @phatskat I added a bit more. I hope this more outlines what I'm having issues with.

Comment: If you visit `Event1/2019/` you'll see the content of the page `Event1`. This is because there's a pagination rewrite rule for a page that's split across multiple pages- it's assuming you want page #2019 of the `Event1` page. You can hook `wp_unique_post_slug` filter to prevent the `-2` being added, but you'll also need to either remove the rewrite rule if you don't want paginated pages, or manually resolve this conflict for incoming requests if you need to have both purely numeric slugs as well as paginated pages.

Comment: I'm throwing in the towel on this one. What you're trying to do seems like it would totally defeat WordPress's core pagination, or conflict with it on such a level that maintaining and debugging it would not be worth the effort. I tried for a while to figure something workable out, but got stuck on rewrites (as @Milo) suggested.